# Tabbar dissappear when push a view in tab menu?

Tags: swift, uitabbar

ProfileVC is a tab menu view. I pushed a SampleView with navigation controller from ProfileVC. If I dismiss SampleView i can see tabBar on ProfileVC but if i present ProfileVC from SampleView i cant see tabBar, it disappear.

Dismiss will be a problem for hiearchy. I need go directly profileView view

Thats push and back codes.

```
@IBAction func goToToolbox(_ sender: Any) {
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.3
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

        let presentedVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ToolboxVC")
        presentedVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        let nvc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: presentedVC)
        present(nvc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }


@objc func didTapCloseButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if let presentedVC = presentedViewController {
            let transition = CATransition()
            transition.duration = 0.3
            transition.type = kCATransitionPush
            transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
            transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
            presentedVC.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
        }
        let profileVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileVC")



       present(profileVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
        presentedVC = nil
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mainly because you are instantiate  the `UIViewController` not the `TabBar`.

And the `UIViewController` is embedded inside the `TabBar` therefore,

You need to give your `TabBarController` on the `IB`  an identifier,

and use that to present it, and it will switch to the first tab automatically.

```
     let TabBar = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyTabBarID")

      present(TabBar, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

However, i don't know why not just `dismiss` the presented `UINavigationController` like this.

```
 self.navController.dismiss(animated: true) {
     self.navController = nil
}
```